# Dynamic sidebar with symfony2.8

Tags: symfony-2.8

I want to have a dynamic sidebar for that I use javascript for the active class property to be running, and it works perfectly, but the problem is with the content level of each sidebar because they are different too

**code html**

```
        <aside class="page-sidebar col-md-2 col-sm-4 affix-top">
                     <section class="widget">
                         <ul class="nav">

                           {% for tache in taches %}
                             <li class=""><a href="#my">{{ tache.titre }}</a></li>
                           {% endfor %}

                         </ul>

                     </section>

         </aside>
          <div class="content-wrapper col-md-10 col-sm-8">
                     <div id="my" class="page-row">
                         {% include "FrontBundle:Default:my.html.twig" %}
                     </div>

          </div>
```

I want to know if there is a solution to recover each sidebar to have access to its content e. Because in the twig my.html.twig I want to display the description of each "tache" {{tache.description}}
And thank you in advance